# Creating instance of ViewModel in screen composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have recently seen a video about common mistakes in Jetpack Compose, where was said that I shouldn't create instance of a ViewModel in composable's parameter.
There was some solution to use state instead of viewmodel in a parameter, but that isn't important for this question.

My question is that why I can't simply create instance of viewmodel inside that composable?

Example how I shouldn't do it:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(viewModel = hiltViewModel<ViewModel>()) {
 ...
}
```

Example of my idea:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
 val viewModel = hiltViewModel<ViewModel>()
 ...
}
```

What are differences between these two approaches and why I shouldn't use second one as well?

Comment: Preview does not resolve or provide hilt dependencies. You have to resolve the dependencies handle creation of viewModel on your own in Preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not make your screen composables reliant on Android `ViewModel`s because it e.g.:

- breaks the *Preview* functionality in Compose,
- makes UI testing more difficult,
- prevents using the screen composables on other platforms than Android which don't use Android-specific `ViewModel`s.

The approach of using a screen state instead of a `ViewModel` as a composable parameter is supposed to eliminate those problems.

Now the real reason why we're doing that is not to *just remove the `ViewModel` parameter* from the composable.

We are doing it to **make the composable completely independent of a `ViewModel`**.

Your "new" approach (putting the `ViewModel` initialization logic inside the composable) doesn't solve the three example issues I've listed. The composable is still using the `ViewModel` - it relies on it.

So the final answer to your question:

> why I shouldn't use second one as well?

Because it still makes the composable reliant on the `ViewModel` - which we really don't want.

Comment: Also, the first code block at least allows you to unit test more easily by swapping the view model. It is used in some of the Compose documentation examples. While there are advantages to avoiding a ViewModel dependency, as you listed, it can become very cumbersome to hoist a lot of state all the way through the Composable hierarchy. There is maybe a balancing act of how high up in the hierarchy to put the ViewModel dependency.